# Doxygen - hide detailed description

Tags: c, doxygen

Is there any way to hide detailed description in doxygen's v1.8.17 generated html files if it's empty?

Currently I am creating a C project documentation using doxygen's grouping mechanisms. Generated by doxygen html pages contain empty detailed description in "Modules" section. I would very much like to get rid of detailed description in generated "Modules" section but keep it in "Files" section.

The screenshot below shows current layout:
[image]

I tried setting both ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC and EXTRACT_ALL field to NO, but it won't work.

Comment: Which doxygen 1.8, i.e.1.8.1 or 1.8.18 or ..., just give `doxygen -v`

Comment: It's doxygen 1.8.17

Comment: I had a quick look at the possibilities of the layout file as well but didn't see a solution. Maybe worth an issue in the doxygen issue tracker: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new